# What's wrong with this Fitnesse test? (decision tables not found)

Tags: testing, automated-tests, fitnesse

```
Cache Load Test

!define testserver {tst1:8080}
!*> Script and Scenario

!|script |
| start | HttpClientFixture |

!|scenario | testCacheLoad 
| setUrl |http://${testserver}/data-service/load/cache |
| check | responseContains | 200 | true |
| check | responseContains | CACHE_LOADER_OK | true |
| show | getResponseBody | | |

*!

Run the scenario test
!| testCacheLoad
```

I want the test to proceed as follows:

- Invoke the URL
- Check the http response code is 200
- Check the JSON response for the string "CACHE_LOADER_OK"
- Display the response (show)

The errors I'm getting from Fitnese are...

- setUrl Could not invoke constructor for setUrl[1]
- check The instance decisionTable_1. does not exist
- responseContains The instance decisionTable_1. does not exist
- true The instance decisionTable_1. does not exist

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the Import table.

Do you have something like:

```
|import|
|com.path.to. HttpClientFixture|
```

somewhere in your test?

That is the most common reason for the missing method type error.

Comment: I don't believe that's the problem...I took the test from an existing test that works in the suite, it was parameterized, I just removed the parameters since the url in this test doesn't use any,

Comment: Oh.  So "set url" is used in another test with another column?  Do you know what the method signature for setUrl looks like?  Is there a single argument version or only a two argument version.  I'm not familiar with this fixture, so I have to ask.